# sh: pdftotext: command not found

Tags: php, pdf, shell-exec, pdftotext

I'm having a PHP page which invokes the pdftotext command to convert a pdf file to a text file and then do some subsequent processing. I use the shell_exec command to execute the pdftotext command.

On execution, I am getting the following error:

```
sh: pdftotext: command not found
```

Code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$url = 'https://testdomain.com/sample.pdf';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents('delta_file.pdf', $contents);
echo shell_exec("pdftotext -layout delta_file.pdf text_contents.txt 2>&1");
```

What am I doing wrong?
I have installed pdftotext.

Any ideas?

Comment: The easiest solution is usually to just specify the full path to the pdftotext command: `shellexec("/usr/bin/pdftotext ...")` (or whatever the actual path is)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From where can we learn the path of pdftotext?

Comment: You can run `type pdftotext` from a shell.

Comment: Okay. I'll check and get back.